# What is the value of the expression $\dfrac13\sqrt{\dfrac{12}{4}}-\left(\dfrac{9\cdot 5^{-2}}{0,5\cdot 2^{-1}}\right)^{-0,5}$?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

$$\dfrac13\sqrt{\dfrac{12}{4}}-\left(\dfrac{9\cdot 5^{-2}}{0,5\cdot 2^{-1}}\right)^{-0,5}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} - \frac{\sqrt{25}}{\sqrt{36}}$$

Comment: @Martin Your edit helped to clarify the question. Nice job on that edit.  But could you also edit your question to include any attempts you made to simplify the expression, or even writing what you know about laws of exponents.

Comment: I didn't know that. I am new to that forum.

Comment: Okay wait a second.

Comment: Do you want to write $\dfrac13\sqrt{\dfrac{12}{4}}-\left(\dfrac{9\cdot 5^{-2}}{0,5\cdot 2^{-1}}\right)^{-0,5}?$

Comment: Yes... I am new and trying to accustom to the commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\dfrac{\sqrt{25}}{\sqrt{36}}=\frac{5}{6}.$$ Thus

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}-\dfrac{5}{6}=\dfrac{2\sqrt{3}-5}{6}.$$

Comment: Yes i have concluded the same answer .. But the answer according to the answers (A , B , C or D ) is incorrect ...